# setup dhcp server - "Job failed to start"

Tags: 12.04, dhcp

I have an `eth0` and `eth1`, `eth0` has dynamic IP-address and on `eth1` I setup static IP-address:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.10.0.1  
netmask 255.0.0.0   
gateway 10.10.0.1
```

and then I setup the [isc-dhcp-server [image: Install isc-dhcp-server]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/isc-dhcp-server) with the following command:

```
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

Finally... I went to this one `/etc/dhcpd.conf` with the following command:

```
default-lease-time 650;

max-lease-time 79520;

option subnet-mask 255.0.0.0;
option broadcast-address 10.10.0.255;
option routers 10.10.0.2;

subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0

{

range 10.10.0.10 10.10.0.250;

}
```

When I try to `sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start`, I get `start: Job failed to start`

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an 8 bit subnet mask an then use the network 10.10.0.0 your subnet should be 10.0.0.0 or change your mask to 255.255.0.0 the later being an illegal subnet.

Answer (score 4):

What does /var/log/syslog say?

isc's dhcpd is a bit picky in terms of the ip subnet parsing and ignoring bits. Suspect that the following may help in your setup:
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0
         ^^^